# Trying to Style Radio button (using background-image)

Tags: html, forms, css, radio-button

I am trying to style a radio button, I am replacing the circle with a background image, when the user clicks it the container the button is in is supposed to have an inner box shadow appear.

I styled the spans grey for simplicity, assume the grey color is a background-image

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CF5qc/

**HTML**

```
<div class="contain">
<span>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="1">
    <label></label>   
</span>
<span>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
    <label></label>   
</span>
<span>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="3">
    <label></label>  
</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contain { width: 300px; margin: 10px auto; overflow:hidden;border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
span { 
    display:block; width:100px; height:100px; border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box; float:left;
}
span:last-of-type { border:none; }
input { width:20px;height:20px;margin:40px; }
input[type=radio]{display:none;}
label {
width:100%;height:100%;display:block; background-color: #f8f8f8; cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your labels aren't associated with any elements. To make this trick work, you'll need to assign the radio buttons an ID and use the `for` attribute on the labels to pair them up.

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" id="rb1" checked />
<label for="rb1"></label>
```