# How do I change the color and style of radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a code to modify but it is not working

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio-1-1" name="radio-1-set" class="regular-radio" checked />
```

**Css**

```
.regular-radio:checked:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    background: #99a1a7;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-shadow: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.regular-radio:checked {
    background-color: #e9ecee;
    color: #99a1a7;
    border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

I need radio box like :-

[image]

Let me know how can I do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this example will give you ideas on what's possible: http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/jChFa

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256992/radio-button-background-image

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to Style Radio button (using background-image)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389095/trying-to-style-radio-button-using-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in css, but not for all the browsers.

The effect on all browsers:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/

A possibility is a custom checkbox with javascript, example:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without javascript.

By default HTML works so that your label will trigger the input. This means that you can hide your input, and put a psudo element on you label. In that way you can style whatever radio button / checkbox you would like. 
Now I didn't test the below code, put it should be close to this.
By the way. The reason for not displaying none on the input, is because it makes IOS crash, for some reason.

```
<label for="test">
<input type="radio" id="test" />
</label>
```

CSS

```
  input {
    position: absolute; 
    left: - 999em;
    }
        label {
        position relative;
        padding-left: 30px;
        }
        label:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
        background: url(yourBackgroundImage.png) no-repeat 0 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 2px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a rounded check box. Not a radio button. Here is how it did.

- Here is the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/X55am/
- Here is some extra: http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

**html**

```
<div class="roundedTwo">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" />
    <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    background: #555;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
/* ROUNDED TWO */
.roundedTwo {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
}

.roundedTwo label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.roundedTwo label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.roundedTwo label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.roundedTwo input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```